# how to dynamically add to html table using javascript Json

Tags: javascript, html, json

This is my code how to dynamically add the html table do not use Jquery. Only use html and javascript. this code was server to client application this client receive the Json object to parse in string . how to add html table.

```
    ## <!doctype html>
  <html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Untitled Document</title>
   <script src="E:\vj\SignalR\json_js\json.js"></script>
    <script src="E:\vj\SignalR\json_js\json2.js"></script>


   <script src="E:\vj\SignalR\json_js\bson\bson.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8100");

 var received_msg;
 var Dictionary=new Dictionary();
 var globalSymbol;
 function WebSocketTest() 
 {                             


        ws.onerror = function () 
        {
            alert("error");
        };

        ws.onopen = function () 
        { 
    alert("Client Connected");

            ws.send("New1");


        };



        ws.onclose = function () 
        {                
            alert("Connection is closed...");
        };

    ws.onmessage=function(evt)
    {
    var msg=evt.data
    alert(msg);
    var jsn=JSON.parse(evt.data);
    //var text =('{"newQuote":' + jsn);


      var tbl = document.getElementById('_table_Quote_ID');
      var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;  
      var iteration = lastRow;
      var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow)
      var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
      var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
      var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
      var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);

        cell1.innerHTML = jsn[0].symbol;
        cell2.innerHTML = jsn[1].bid;
        cell3.innerHTML = jsn[2].ask;
        cell4.innerHTML = jsn[3].high;
        cell5.innerHTML = jsn[4].low;
```

Comment: What output/error do you get with your current code?

Comment: output is only add single row at a runtime

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I understand this you say 'how can I create dynamic table ' , I hope this code can fix your problem

```js
   <script>
        var length = 5 // this is your data lenght i write 5 for examples
        var table = "<table border = '1' cellpadding='10'>";
        for (var i = 0 ; i < length ; i++) {
            table += "<tr>";
            for (var j = 0 ; j < length ; j++) {
                table += "<td> value </td>";
            }
            table += "</tr>";
        }
        table += "<table>";
        document.write(table);
    </script>
```